# SQL Server LOGIN problem while connecting it from outside

Tags: sql-server

I have installed one instance of SQL Server 2012 in my local machine at my office network which was connecting very smoothly at my office network. But from tomorrow I have shifted my office location and that instance of SQL Server not connecting. It is showing the below message:

[image: The error message]

Please help to solve this.

Comment: Is the firewall port open? Does the server allow remote connections?

Comment: That's not a login problem. That's a connectivity problem with several duplicate questions and very good answers.

Comment: Follow these steps: [Steps to troubleshoot SQL connectivity issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/).

Comment: Could be a number of things. Can you ping the server? If not, check firewall settings, and that the DNS entry is correct.

Comment: If you search for the error message you'll find duplicate questions and guides that explain how to solve connectivity problems. `the target machine actively refused it` is a TCP error that means a firewall is blocking that particular port or that there's nothing listening to it (the server isn't running for example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: Thank you all... The problem is now solved